# MySQL / PDO / PHP - SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value:

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I can see this has been asked a few times, however in all previously asked instances I can see that the answer was that the parameter was not in fact an integer. Mine definitely is an integer, at least in the PHP.

I am trying to load a pdf into a MySQL DB as a BLOB. The file appears to be passed correctly from the PHP form, and I have checked that the size variable is actually an integer, which it is.

Code snippets:-

```
//get file info and data
$name = $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name'];
$mime = $_FILES['uploaded_file']['type'];
//$data = file_get_contents($_FILES  ['uploaded_file']['tmp_name']);
$tmpName = $_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'];
$fp = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
$data = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
fclose($fp);
$size = intval($_FILES['uploaded_file']['size']);
$created = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

echo "captured fields";
echo "</br>";
echo $name;
echo "</br>";
echo $mime;
echo "</br>";
echo gettype($size), "</br>";
echo $size;
echo "</br>";
echo $created;
echo "</br>";
echo $enteredID;
echo "</br>";

//prepare the query
$query = "
    INSERT INTO `file` (
        `name`, `mime`, `size`, `data`, `created`, `category`, `relatedID`
    )
    VALUES (
        ':Name', ':Mime', ':Size', ':Data', NOW(), ':ScanType', ':EnteredID'
    )";

$sth = $dbLink->prepare($query);
$sth->bindParam(':Name',$name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->bindParam(':Mime',$mime, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->bindParam(':Size',$size,  PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->bindParam(':Data',$data,  PDO::PARAM_LOB);
//$sth->bindParam(':Created', $created, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->bindParam(':ScanType', $scanType,  PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->bindParam(':EnteredID', $enteredID,  PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->execute();
```

The echo statements are me trying to work out where the errors are. I also tried file_get_contents and fopen as I had this working in PHP 5.5 but having updated to PHP7 (ubuntu 16.04) I needed to update a stack of code. That may also give a clue as some of the settings in MySQL appear to be different and I have read about MySQL settings however I am reluctant to change those until I understand more about them.

MySQL table is:-

```
Field     | Type                | Null | Key | Default      | Extra          
+---------+---------------------+------+-----+--------------+----------------+
id        | int(10) unsigned    | NO   | PRI | NULL         | auto_increment |
name      | varchar(255)        | NO   |     | Untitled.txt |                
mime      | varchar(50)         | NO   |     | text/plain   |                 
size      | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   |     | 0            |                
data      | mediumblob          | NO   |     | NULL         |            
created   | datetime            | NO   |     | NULL         |               
category  | varchar(8)          | NO   |     | NULL         |               
relatedID | varchar(10)         | NO   |     | NULL         |              
newSize   | int(20)             | YES  |     | NULL         |              
+-----------+---------------------+------+-----+--------------+----------------+
```

As you can see, I have tried adding a new column in case it was the bigint that was causing the issue, but it made no difference.

The variable type is definitely an integer, so why does MySQL not accept it as such? I must be missing something however I can't for the life of me see what it is.

Comment: You don't need quotes round bind variable names (i.e. in the SQL statement)

Comment: Quoting the parameters in your INSERT query confuses the interpreter. Using prepared statements removes the need for you to quote your own variables.

Comment: Perfect - thank you both - that's solved it. I didn't think it would hurt to leave the quotes, but I know better now :)